# get_schedule (get_availability) with python api O365

Tags: python, python-3.x, office365

I am trying to get other person's availability time (displayed on outlook).
My company uses Office 365 for managing appointments.
So, I write down these programs to get the data, but it doesn't work.

```
credentials = (xxxx, yyyy)
account = Account(credentials)

if not account.is_authenticated:
    account.authenticate(scopes=['basic', 'calendar_all'])

schedule = account.schedule()
schedules = ['xxxxx@hotmail.com', 'yyyyy@hotmail.com']
start = dt.datetime(2019, 10, 30, 19, 45, tzinfo=ja) 
end = dt.datetime(2019, 10, 31, 19, 45, tzinfo=ja) 

cal = schedule.get_availability(schedules, start, end, interval=30)

print(cal)
```

error massage

```
'Schedule' object has no attribute 'get_availability'
```

I know this error is related to the attribute subject, but I don't know what should I change. Any guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: `get_availability` method was added 2 days back in python api, check: https://github.com/O365/python-o365/commit/5d546f0818941f991469cdbc7a1853493ba01ee2 make sure you have master build

Comment: thank you for your advice! I make sure I have master build, it isn't latest version. I chenge the program, it work well!